# Launching Script based on Eval Figure

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

```
 $(".app-launch").on("click", function () {
    var appId = this.id;

    // Check if Function is running.
    if (typeof eval('$' + appId).start == 'undefined') {
         eval('$' + appId).start();
     }
 }
```

The eval just causes it to come back and say $XXXXXX is not defined and kills the java-script execution.  Is there anyway to prevent it from killing the execution and continuing? This function is either launching the application or loading the javascript first and then launching the application, so this check is there to determine if the javascript has already been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First, stop using `eval`. If you want dynamically namable variables, use an object.

Then you can just test the type of the object before you try to access its `start` property.

```
var objects = {};
var appId = "thing";

objects[appId] = { start: foo; }

if (
    typeof objects[appId] !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof objects[appId].start === 'function'
   ) {
    objects[appId]();
}
```

Comment: This example fails.  For this example to work thing must be in quotes.  Thing must be a string OR you must do it like objects = { thing : { start : foo } };  Thank you for showing me this way, I hope I in some way helped you as well.  Please fix the answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
eval('$("' + appId + '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve a global variable, just use the associative array syntax `window['$'+appId]`

Also, the reason your code is breaking is because you are checking if the start method is defined, whereas it is $XXXXXX that does not exist. Check if $XXXXXX exists before referencing the method. Also, you are calling the method if it is not defined, which makes no sense.

Also eval.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2sys/) that shows what is wrong. Here is a fixed [version](http://jsfiddle.net/R2sys/2/).

Comment: +1 Yea I think I'd use a completely different approach than how OP is doing this...but if stuck with this code, this would be how I'd do it.